# % notation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

I've read [% notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) but I could not find the explanation about the followings.

Example 1: The following code with `%` outputs `i`. Obviously `%` changes `i` to a string. But I am not sure what actually `%` is doing.

```
irb(main):200:0> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].each{ |row| p row.map{ |i|  % i } }
["i", "i", "i"]
["i", "i", "i"]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
irb(main):201:0> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].each{ |row| p row.map{ |i|  i } }
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Example 2: It seems `%2d` adding 2 spaces in front of a number. Again, I am not sure what `%2d` is doing.

```
irb(main):194:0> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].each{ |row| p row.map{|i| "%2d" % i } }
[" 1", " 2", " 3"]
[" 4", " 5", " 6"]
[" 7", " 8", " 9"]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Where can I find the documentation about these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the doc - [*You may also create strings using %:*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).

> There are two different types of % strings %q(...) behaves like a single-quote string (no interpolation or character escaping) while %Q behaves as a double-quote string.....

In your first example `p row.map{|i|  % i }` as per the above doc `% i`  creates a string `"i"`.

Examples :-

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |i| % i } # => ["i", "i", "i"]
% i  # => "i"
```

Just remember as doc is saying -

> Any combination of adjacent single-quote, double-quote, percent strings will be concatenated **as long as a percent-string is not last**.

From the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation)

> Any single non-alpha-numeric character can be used as the delimiter, %[including these], %?or these?,...

Now in your case it is `%<space>i<space>`. Which in the link I mentioned just above are `%[..]`, `%?..?` etc.. That is why `%<space>i<space>` gives `"i"`. (I used `<space>` to show there is a *space*)

Read [`Kernel#format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format)

> Returns the string resulting from applying format_string to any additional arguments. Within the format string, any characters other than format sequences are copied to the result.
>
> The syntax of a format sequence is follows.

```
%[flags][width][.precision]type
```

> A format sequence consists of a percent sign, followed by optional flags, width, and precision indicators, then terminated with a field type character. The field type controls how the corresponding sprintf argument is to be interpreted, while the flags modify that interpretation.

Your last question actually points to a method [`str % arg → new_str`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25).

If *IRB* made you fool, like made me while trying to understand `% i`, don't worry, have a look - [why in IRB modulo string literal(%) is behaving differently ?](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4938401#new). Good answer *Matthew Kerwin* is given there.

Comment: In irb, when I type % i doesn't return anything.

Comment: @shin See the link, I have given in the answer. :-)

Comment: I forgot a space after i. Thanks.